# Update all global activated packages

Tags: bash, dart, dart-pub

I came up with this command

```bash
pub global list -v 2>/dev/null | awk '{split($0, a," "); printf \
  "pub global activate "; if(a[8]=="") printf a[3]; else printf \
  "-sgit " a[8]; print "" }' | xargs -0 bash -c
```

to update all my globally activated packages.

```
pub global list -v
```

outputs

```
FINE: Pub 1.9.0-edge.43835
MSG : dart_style 0.1.3
MSG : den 0.1.5
MSG : linter 0.0.1 from Git repository "git@github.com:dart-lang/linter.git"
MSG : polymer 0.15.5+1
MSG : stagehand 0.1.5+4
MSG : test_runner 0.2.16
```

The above command generates these commands from the output

```
pub global activate dart_style 
...
pub global activate -sgit "git@github.com:dart-lang/linter.git"
...
```

That's quite complicated. 
Is there an easier way?

Comment: I don't think that manual split call is doing anything for you so you can drop it. You could clean up the awk a bit more with ternary operator but that's not a big deal/win. This sounds like something you should take up with `pub` to me about not having a better way to do this. Also that awk command isn't spitting out NUL-delimited lines so that `xargs` call doesn't look like it should be working as written.

Comment: +Etan Reisner This is why I added the dart tags. Maybe someone knows a better way without all this string manipulation. I understand the ternary argument but not the comment about NUL-delimited lines. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: The `-0` argument to `xargs` says "split input on NUL bytes instead of newlines" but your awk script is outputting normal newline delimited lines so `xargs` isn't splitting it at all. Though, now that I'm writing that, it doesn't make much difference (except not really making use of `xargs` at all) since bash is going to handle the newlines itself anyway (but you could just use `| bash -s` with that instead.

Comment: I tried it. `| bash -s` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't need to apply a `split` in the `awk`.

Another improve , get rid of the `if` contional and use the `ternary` operator (as *Etan* explain in the comments):

```
awk '{var=$8==""?$3:"-sgit "$8;print "pub global activate "var }'
```

The final stuff should be something close to:

```
pub global list -v 2>/dev/null |\
awk '{var= $8==""? $3: "-sgit " $8
      print "pub global activate "var }'| bash -s
```

Alternatively a `system` call can be done inside the `awk` code:

```
pub global list -v 2>/dev/null |\
awk '{var=$8=="" ?  $3: "-sgit " $8                                       
      cmd="pub global activate "var
      system(cmd)
      close(cmd)}'
```

Comment: As +Etan Reisner wrote in the above comment. `| xargs -0` doesn't do anything in this case. I have to add `print ""` (`... $8 ; print ""}`) to get a line break and make each line execute on it's own.

Comment: Ups @EtanReisner is right again :) Günter , see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

As I don't speak bash nor awk fluently and was interested in such feature, I ended up writing this tool...in dart (yes I know it does not really answer the question but that is where I landed when searching for such feature)

```
$ pub global activate pubglobalupdate
```

Then all current global activated packages can be updated using:

```
$ pubglobalupdate
```

it works on linux, mac and windows! (https://github.com/tekartik/pubglobalupdate.dart)

Comment: Ok I listened to you. The package is now on pub (response updated)

Answer (score 1):

In one line, you can do this.

```bash
dart pub global list | awk '{print "dart pub global activate "$1}' | bash -s
```